# Enabling/disabling bitwise meaning in Unix serial programming

Tags: c, unix, serial-port, bitwise-operators

I'm learning about Unix serial programming and I have noticed two uses of bitwise operators as follows :

```
tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // Disable RTS/CTS hardware flow control
tty.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;  // Enable RTS/CTS hardware flow control
```

any appearance of **&= and ~** means disabling and **|=** means enabling a feature. Is this some universal convention for enabling/disabling features when dealing with flags and bitwise operations? in other words, are those uses of bitwise operations used specifically for this purpose? or there's a mask behind this that Unix uses and it's different with every other library? e.g. I can use |= for disabling instead of enabling features.

After setting/clearing the bit array, how does the library check which features were set and call events accordingly? does it use if-statements for each bit? I'm trying to build something similar and I wonder if using if-statements is efficient after the user passes the features he wants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm learning about Unix serial programming

To be clear, you seem to be referring to the POSIX interface for serial terminals, aka termios.  Note that this API combines the configuration of serial ports with serial terminals.
Also note that the bit values for termios attributes depend on the specific OS and CPU architecture.

---

> I have noticed two uses of bitwise operators ...

Which are formally known as [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Refer to [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237) for the reasoning for using bitwise operations with termios attributes.

> When you set terminal modes, you should call **tcgetattr()** first to get the current modes of the particular terminal device, modify only those modes that you are really interested in, and store the result with **tcsetattr()**.
>
> ... you should start with the current value of the member and alter only the flags whose values matter in your program, leaving any other flags unchanged.

---

> any appearance of **&=** and **~** means disabling and **|=** means enabling a feature. Is this some universal convention for enabling/disabling features when dealing with flags and bitwise operations?

Sort of, for software anyway.
Beware that you are conflating Boolean values & arithmetic with features and enabling/disabling them.
For termios (and the typical API), a binary `1` is equated to the condition `the feature is enabled`.
However some interfaces, especially hardware interfaces, might use inverted logic, where a `1` means de-asserted or `false`.
For example most RS-232 modem control and handshake signals use inverted logic.

---

> in other words, are those uses of bitwise operations used specifically for this purpose?

The *"purpose"* is to *set* and/or *clear* only specific bits in structure members (without modifying other bits/sflags), which will communicate to the OS the terminal and communication settings your program wants to use (when your program passes the termios structure using the **tcsetattr()** syscall).

In general your program will not know the pre-existing termios configuration, nor should it care.  So the best practice (for robustness/portability) is for your program to enable and/or disable *all* attributes/flags as needed (using bitwise operations).

---

> or there's a mask behind this that Unix uses and it's different with every other library?

*"Mask"*?

Termios is an API (i.e. application program interface for interacting with an OS subsystem), not a *"library"* (i.e. a collection of routines linked with your application program).

Are you asking a XY question?

---

> I can use |= for disabling instead of enabling features.

A Boolean OR operation using a `1` bit will always result in a set bit.
So if the set bit means that the feature is enabled (which is typical for the termios API), then the answer is "no, that will not disable a feature".
The answer could be affirmative if inverted logic is being used.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this some universal convention for enabling/disabling features when dealing with flags and bitwise operations?

Yes. Generally, `|= x` sets one or many bits and `&= ~x` clears one or many bits.

However, the `~` operator is problematic since it comes with built-in integer promotion, so you will often find such code more properly written as `&= (uint8_t)~x` etc, where `uint8_t` is the intended type.

Similarly, it is fairly common that C library APIs expect the user to provide a number of bitwise OR:ed bit flags as input. For example: `func(GIMME_THIS | GIMME_THAT);`.

---

> After setting/clearing the bit array, how does the library check which features were set and call events accordingly? does it use if-statements for each bit?
> I wonder if using if-statements is efficient

That's quite likely, yes. It is *memory efficient* since it saves a bit of memory to group related bit flags together in the same bit field, rather than to store them as individual variables.

Otherwise, if you are looking for execution speed efficiency, then it is generally more efficient to use different variables, at least on mid- to high-end CPUs - 32 bitters or larger. Since these CPUs have alignment requirements and prefer to work with 32 bit chunks.

But we're talking about manual micro optimizations here - manual code optimization is skilled work and requires lots of understanding of the specific target. So it is generally not something that beginner to intermediately skilled programmers should worry about. Instead focus on writing *readable* code and let the compiler worry about optimizations. As it turns out, readable code often also results in efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want enable and disable from same operator, just instead of `|=` use `^=`(XOR) and `|=` can't disable because it assigns `1` if one of bits is `1` then it can't disable

Comment: How does the library decides what to do with the bit array later? does it use if statements to know which bit was on and then apply more statements if that so?

Comment: so assume that I have 4 bit, every bit has a function e.g. one to disable/enable CTS. then I need 4 if statements to check every bit if it's 'on', and then I write some actions if that's the case. is that how you do it? with if statements?  or there's some other way?

Comment: @JohnSall for example you have bit masks, you need to combine them for example first is `0b00000001` and `0b00000010` you have to combine them with `|=` then you mask becomes `0b00000011`  and with if  statements (using `&`) you enable events or call you can call function, whatever you want

Comment: @JohnSall without `if` you also can do something like this `(mask1 & mask2) && callFunction()` it have to be quicker. It's similar but it's branchless

Comment: *"instead of `|=` use `^=`(XOR)"* -- Exclusive OR is not a general replacement for a plain OR.

Comment: @sawdust I know but for enabling and disabling it's better choice

Comment: That presumes that the program knows the existing value is the opposite state.  That may not be even true, so it is not *"better"*.

Comment: @sawdust I am talking about that situation, exceptions are everywhere

Comment: XOR is used for _toggling_, when the intention is explicitly to toggle bits. `void enable_CTS (void) { whatever ^= CTS; }` is obviously a completely broken function.